# .focus() doesn't work on an input while orher attributes works

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I have a classic `table / thead / tbody` structure, which I add a line at the end of the tbody. The line contains only an `input` element. The code works in Firefox 3.6 *but not in Chrome v5 or IE8*. I'm using jQuery 1.4.2.

Does not work:
`$("#" + AJAX_ID).parent().find('tr:last > td:nth-child(2) > input').focus();`

Does work:
`$("#" + AJAX_ID).parent().find('tr:last > td:nth-child(2) > input').css('background-color', 'red');`

even setting an ID on the input, and using `document.getElementBuId('id').focus()` doesn't work.

*** edit ***

The site is pretty complex (mix of template / static html and dynamic html), but the table
looks like this (rendered html in chrome, layout via tidy) : http://pastebin.com/PHqxAEVm

*** edit 2 ***

Even `$("#lectures").find("input:last").focus();` called from the ajax callback doesn't do anything.. `$("#lectures").find("input:last").css('background-color', 'red');` turns one red though, but the focus goes to the address bar.

Here's a dump of the returned object from the selector:
http://pastebin.com/Jdw1TZXf

*** edit 3 ***

Here's the JavaScript code that builds the table: http://pastebin.com/cbCfi0UY
on page load, `oContainer` is `$("#lectures")` while after the ajax call it's `$("#" + AJAX_ID).parent()`, which is supposed to point to the table's tbody

*** edit 4 ***

Hard problem... here's the full `lectures.js` file: http://pastebin.com/Jkg0DZqa
`batisses` and `compteurs` are json objects loaded via the template. the user select a `batisse` then a `compteur` then press a button that calls `buildAjout()`, which calls in this example `buildElectric($("#lectures"), compteur);`. Once the line is filled bu the user, `onBlurLecture(tr_parent)` is called, the data is sent to the server via AJAX and `function callback_compteurs_lecture_add(AJAX_ID)` is called after the ajax call is complete. The function `SendCommand` is a custom function which use jQuery ajax.

The creation of the first input line (and the focus) works, but not the one created in the callback of the ajax.

*** edit 5 ***

The full rendered page looks like: http://pastebin.com/UfBYcjX3
I shortened the `batisses` variable. The (full) page has no JavaScript errors.
In Chrome's JavaScript console, I cannot focus the inputs.

*** edit 6 ***

Wrong function name in this question for `SendCommand`. fixed.

Solution found:
[.focus() doesn't work on an input while orher attributes works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760901/focus-doesnt-work-on-an-input-while-orher-attributes-works/2766491#2766491)

Comment: I downgraded to 1.4.1, and `focus()` is working fine for me in those browsers. Some HTML would be nice.

Comment: I added a dump of the rendered HTML in the main question. oh sorry I have jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: Well, I had an answer that gave two potential solutions, but it was down-voted with no explanation. I have a feeling that it was because I gave criticism of the two answers here that are incorrect. So I deleted mine. Sorry.

Comment: @Patrick: I didn't down vote you, I'll accept any criticism, it's another way to learn :)... actually it seems like everyone got a -1 with no explanation, oh well.

Comment: @fudgey: No, not you. There was another answer that is now gone (likely suspect). Your solution seemed fine. I don't know why you lost your vote, but I down-voted the other two (now one) after mine was knocked down. You can see my explanation for the one remaining.

Comment: @Sirber - I'll bring mine back online.

Comment: @Sirber - If focus is going to the location bar, it makes me think that the page is refreshing. Are you clicking an `a` element to trigger the code? If so, try placing `return false;` at the end of its event handler.

Comment: Well, I don't see where AJAX is being called. I can't find any `SendDocument` in the code from **edit 4**. Is this `callback_compteurs_lecture_add(AJAX_ID)` being called from the `success:` callback in your ajax call?

Comment: sorry I didn't see those comments. typo sorry the function is  `SendCommand`. Updating the question. Yes the callback is called from `success:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it!

I use "tab" (tabulation) to switch to the next input while writing in them. At the last one, the focus goes out of the window so I cannot set it. I converted the last column "status" into a `input` so it gets the focus while `onBlur` is executed. When the ajax load callback is called, the new line is added and the input is focused as it should.

Chrome: works
Firefox: works
IE8: works (with fix)

spent 1½ day on that lol

thanks everyone!

Comment: on a side note, IE8 adds two lines since `.blur()` is triggered when the input lose it's focus (via code). I had to add an array of "already sent" IDs so it doesn't execute twice.

Answer (score 3):

What ID are you targeting? Because if I replace `$("#" + AJAX_ID)` with `$('table')` it works -> [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QPJhq/1/) (at least in Chrome)

and if I wrap the function inside a `$(document).ready(function(){...})` it works in IE -> [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QPJhq/2/)

---

I'm still looking to see what the problem might be, but I have a few comments about your code so far.

1. I haven't tested this, but I creating a jQuery object then appending another object inside ends up taking a lot of time because of the number of function calls. I've found it easier to just build up a string and only use one append. This example makes it easy to read:

   ```
   var table = '\
    <table style="width: 100%">\
     <thead>\
      <tr>\
       <th>Numéro</th>\
       <th>litre</th>\
       <th style='width: 100px;'>Status</th>\
      </tr>';

   // append more to the string
   table += '<tbody>.....</tbody></table>';
   $('body').append(table);
   ```
2. I found this bit of code and I just wanted to show you that you can shorten it:

   ```
   $("#no_batisse").css('display', 'none');
   $("#lectures").html("");
   $("#lectures").css('display', '');
   ```

   shortens to:

   ```
   $("#no_batisse").hide();
   $("#lectures").empty().hide();
   ```
3. Instead of calling this function after each row addition, you could try adding a `live` function once that works with dynamically added content:

   ```
   $(oLigne).find("input").blur(function() { onBlurLecture(oLigne); });
   ```

   try running this when you initialize the script (just once)

   ```
   $('#lecture').find('input').live('blur', function(){
    onBlurLecture( $(this).closest('tr') );
   })
   ```

I'll keep looking!

Comment: on page load, javascript creates the table then add a line (id=AJAX_ID) with empty inputs, and focus the second field (working). Once all the input are filled, they are sent to the server with the line ID (AJAX_ID), the server save the request, and send AJAX_ID back so I can update the last field (status) and add a new line above it. Then, focus the second field (failing). I'm pretty sure that just playing with the html dump will work, but in the real code it doesn't.

Comment: If you are loading the row dynamically with ajax, then you should set the focus in the load callback function.

Comment: I'm in the load callback function. whatever I do I can only cahnge the CSS of the input, I cannot focus it, even with patrick's answer.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you may be setting focus on another element unintentionally. I set up a third demo (http://jsfiddle.net/QPJhq/3/) that works on FF, IE and Chrome... so I don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**

If your code is being triggered via some element that has a default behavior (like an `<a>` element), try adding `return false;` to the end of its callback.

Alternatively, if you give a parameter to the event handler's function, like `function(e) {...}`, you can call `e.preventDefault()` from within the callback instead of `return false;`.

---

First, I don't know if this is the issue, but IDs can not start with a number.

Second, which element has the AJAX ID that are you using? You'll get different results depending on that.

To avoid any ID issues, you could do:

```
$("#lectures").find('tr:last > td:nth-child(2) > input').focus();
```

or if you want it to be relative, do:

```
$("#" + AJAX_ID).closest('tbody').find('tr:last > td:nth-child(2) > input').focus();
```

Comment: Down-voted why? I **really, really hope** it is because there is an error in my answer, and not because I pointed out why two of the other answers are wrong.

Comment: To clarify my comment, one of the two wrong answers is now removed. fudgey seems to be on the right track.

Comment: I added "ID" in front of the number. Both doesn't work. maybe I have something wrong in the creation of the second line.. but the DOM seems fine.

Comment: the code is triggered via `blur()` on each `input`, blur call jquery/ajax and ajax calls my callback function. `return false;` didn't help :(

Comment: @Sirber: But you say that the user presses a button. What is that button? And do I understand correctly that the ajax is working and you are receiving the response you expect?

Comment: They select one building then a "power meter", then they press a button to build the rest of the interface which is different for each kind of "power meter". On every input field of the input line, there's  an onblur function to validate the line and send the ajax if the line is full. I addes the javascript in **edit4** and the html in **edit5**

Comment: The suggestion of calling preventDefault on the event worked in my case, where I was setting focus on an input after the user clicked a span element.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to trigger `.focusin()` (this was added in jQuery's 1.4) [See documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/).

Comment: same thing, it doesn't focus on the input :(

Comment: I am sorry about that, I will now `focusin` on the other part of your code that might be the problem :)

Comment: `focusin()` doesn't give focus to an element, but rather detects whether or not focus was received. From docs: *The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus.* The issue here is getting focus in the first place.